# Return to the same section on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On ma webpage I have a form with validation field. When user put not correct data to form and click "send" button a view flip back to the top page and doesn't see form. Then he must scroll down to see and enter valid data. I using this code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ContactForm contact)
        {
                return View("Index");
        }
```

I would like that after put not correct data, user must see form section (name of section is "#contact") with validation info (what is wrong) but not top page like is present.

Comment: You must use j script to do that. Use jquery validation and microsoft.jquery.unobtrusive.validation

Answer (score 3):

**Client side**

If you are using `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` files in your page and enabled client side unobutrusive validation in your web app, It does client side validation before submitting the form to the server and show the validation error messages in your page. In that case you do not need to scroll to the same section as your page is not reloading.

To enable client side validation, you should add the below 2 entries to your web config's AppSettings section.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and include the [`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/) along with it's dependencies(jQuery) in your view/layout.

**Sever side**

When `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false`, you should return the posted object back to the view. To scroll to this particular section, What you should do is, set some flag i n your action method, and use that to determine whether to scroll or not and use javascript to scroll to this location.We can use native [`scrollTop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) method to do this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ContactForm contact)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // to do : Save and redirect
   }
   ViewBag.ValidationFailed="Yes"; // flag to handle the client side scroll !
   return View("Index",contact);
}
```

Make sure you have used the proper html helper methods to show the validation error messages.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
   <div class="form-group" id="contact">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
   </div>
   <input type="submit"/>
}
@section Scripts
{
  <script>
    $(function(){
       if("@ViewBag.ValidationFailed"==="Yes")
       {
         // get the contact div's top position and use that as the scrollTop value.
         $(window).scrollTop($("#contact").position().top);
       }
    });
  </script>
}
```

I am not a usability expert, but you may consider putting the  `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` on the top of your page so that even if javascript fails to scroll to the specific location, user will be able to see the error message on the page relaod.